# how to get the value of how many cells of a column have data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi everyone im trying to make something i have a table like:

```
 <table width="49%" border="1" align="left" cellspacing="0" id="table_left">
<tr id="left_tittle">
  <td width="25%"><strong>Animal</strong></td>
  <td width="25%"><strong>Hierro</strong></td>
  <td width="35%"><strong>Clasificación</strong></td>
  <td width="15%"><strong>Peso</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml1" style="width:96%" align="center"/></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro1" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf1" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso1" style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml2" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro2" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf2" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso2" style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml3" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro3" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf3" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso3" style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml4" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro4" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf4" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso4" style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml5" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro5" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf5" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso5" style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml6" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro6" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf6" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso6" style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
```

i want to know how many cells of the tipe animal have valid data or are different of null

im trying some java script but this all i have

```
    $('#table_left tr:not(#left_tittle)').bind('keyup change', function() {
        var variable = "";
        var count = 0;
        for ( var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
            variable = 'anml'+i;
            var table = document.getElementById('anml'+i).value;

        }
        });
```

everything i try doesnt work, i dont know what im doing wrong

Edit: some code changes.

```
  <table width="49%" border="1" align="left" cellspacing="0" id="table_left">
<tr id="left_tittle">
  <td width="25%"><strong>Animal</strong></td>
  <td width="25%"><strong>Hierro</strong></td>
  <td width="35%"><strong>Clasificación</strong></td>
  <td width="15%"><strong>Peso</strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
    <span id="oAnimal">
    <input name="anml" type="text" id="anml1" class="col1"
    required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre el codigo del animal')"
    style="width:96%" align="center"/>
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre el codigo del animal</span></span></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
    <span id="oHierro">
    <input name="hierro3" type="text" id="hierro1" 
    required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre el hierro del animal')"
    style="width:96%" align="center" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre el hierro del animal</span></span></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
    <span id="oCls">
    <input name="clsf" type="text" id="clsf1" 
    required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre la clasificacion del animal')"
    style="width:96%" align="center" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre la clasificacion del animal</span></span></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
    <span id="oPso">
    <input name="pso" type="text" id="pso1" class="colPeso"
    required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('Por favor entre el peso del animal')"
    style="width:93%" align="center" />
  <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Por favor entre el peso del animal</span></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml2" class="col1"
  style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro2" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf2" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso2" class="colPeso"
  style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml3" class="col1"
  style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro3" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf3" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso3" class="colPeso"
  style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml4" class="col1"
  style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro4" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf4" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso4" class="colPeso"
  style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml5" class="col1"
  style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro5" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf5" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso5" class="colPeso"
  style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml6" class="col1"
  style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro6" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf6" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso6" class="colPeso"
  style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><label for="textfield"></label>
  <input name="animal" type="text" id="anml7" class="col1"
  style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="hierro"></label>
  <input name="hierro" type="text" id="hierro7" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="clasificacion"></label>
  <input name="clasificacion" type="text" id="clsf7" style="width:96%" align="center" /></td>
  <td><label for="peso"></label>
  <input name="peso" type="text" id="pso7" class="colPeso"
  style="width:93%" align="center" /></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What defines something as valid? Just being filled out at all? Is the problem that table is always null? Also you're using `jQuery` so you might as well do `$('#anml' + i )` rather than document...

Comment: by now i just need that the cell have something, but everything i try for count the cells of that specific row, failed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $("#table_left input").bind("blur", function () {
        checkValidInput($(this));
    });
});

function checkValidInput(e) {
    var name = e.attr("name");
    var val = e.val();
    //check required (add required to class attribute)
    //e.g <input name="animal" class='required'
    if (e.hasClass("required") && val.length == 0) {
        //do something
        alert(name + " is null");
    }

    //validation with specify name

    switch (name) {
        case "hierro":
            //do validation
            if (val != 'hello') 
                alert(name + "Please enter hello");
            break;
    }
}
```

You need something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/7w8vE/1/

Comment: thanks man for taking your time and help me, man right now im not trying to validate the cell, i just want to count how many cells of the column animal have anything, and asign it to a function variable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for this:

```
 $('#table_left tr:not(#left_tittle)').bind('input', function (event) {        
 if ($("#"+event.target.id).val() != null && $("#"+event.target.id).val() != "")     
 {
     alert("id:" + event.target.id);
     alert("content: "+$("#"+event.target.id).val());
 }
 });
```

check this out:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whyach/NxUW8/)

and I modified another version, you can do whatever you want by editing the example I created here:

```
 $('#table_left').bind('input', function () {
 var ids = new Array();
 var vals = new Array();  
 $('#table_left td').each(function () {         
     if ($(this).find("input").val() != null && $(this).find("input").val().trim() != "") {
         ids.push($(this).find("input").attr("id"));
         vals.push($(this).find("input").val());
         //alert("id: " + $(this).find("input").attr("id"));
         //alert("content: " + $(this).find("input").val());
     };
 });

 if(ids.length>0){
     alert(ids);
     alert(vals);
 }
```

});

this is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whyach/wPgeG/).

Comment: im trying something like this but i cant get it work $('#table_left tr:not(#left_tittle)').bind('keyup change', function() {
      var variable = "";
   var count = 0;
   for ( var i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
    variable = $('#anml' + i ).find("input").val();
    //console.log(variable);
    if ( variable != null ){
     count = count + 1;
     console.log( variable + " " + count);
    }
   }
   console.log(count);
   
  });

Comment: @Alejandro Hinestrosa 
check this jsfiddle.
(jsfiddle.net/whyach/mN8LP)
Please also note that bind keyup together with change may lead to double trigger of this jquery event. 
I would prefer use 'input' instead.

Comment: man thanks for you help!, i want to make the sum o de cells that have data on a specific column, in this case i give the class "col1" how i select that specific column with your code? thanks!

Comment: @Alejandro Hinestrosa
I guess this one works for what you want.
http://jsfiddle.net/whyach/96KbY/